# Cкриншoт части страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, python, веб-программирование

У меня есть html страница, на ней большая (размером) таблица с картинками и текстами. Мне нужно сделать из этой таблицы картинку в формате .jpg и в оригинальном разрешении и сразу без открытия этой страницы предложить пользователю её скачать.

Как такое можно реализовать? Возможно что-то на html, js, php?

Comment: чекни `chromedriver convert page to pdf`

Comment: @Andrio Skur мне нужно именно jpg

Comment: но pdf легко конвертируеться в jpg